# Sed: delete lines after a pattern for all occurences

Tags: bash, sed

I needed some help with sed. I am trying to delete 3 lines after a pattern *for all occurrences* in a file. I do

```
sed '/pattern/,+3d' file.
```

This only deletes 3 lines and the pattern for the first occurrence but just deletes the pattern for the second occurrence but not the lines after which is really confusing. Can anyone please help with what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think *awk* is better for the task. For example,

```
$ cat file
1
2
4
a0
1
a1
1
2
3
4
5
```

Run

```
awk '
flag   { i ++            }
i == 3 { flag = 0        }
!flag
/a/    { flag = 1; i = 0 }
' file
```

Output

```
1
2
4
a0
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/regexp/{p;:a;n;//ba;n;//ba;n;//ba;d};p' file
```

If the regexp is encountered, print the current line and then delete the following 3 lines. At any time whilst reading these 3 lines, the regexp occurs, reset the count.

If the regexp is also to be deleted, use:

```
sed -n '/regexp/{:a;n;//ba;n;//ba;n;//ba;d};p' file
```